# How do I include the first initial number in the output?

Tags: java, while-loop

So I'm trying to make a collatz sequence that runs until it reaches is 1 but, it doesn't include the number I entered as the argument.

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    
       collatz(17);
    
    }
public static void collatz(int n) {
    while(n!=1) {
    if (n%2==0) {
        n/=2;
        
    }
    else {
        n=3*n+1;
    }
    System.out.println(n);
    
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    collatz(39);
}

public static void collatz(int n) {
    while (n != 1) {
        System.out.println(n);
        if (n % 2 == 0) {
            n /= 2;
        } else {
            n = 3 * n + 1;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(n);

}
```